# output as per requirement in sql code

Tags: sql

input: '1,2,4,5,C1,C2,C5,C7,C8,C9,T1,T5,T6,T10'

output: 1-2,4-5,C1-C2,C5,C7-C9,T1,T5-T6,T10

here when we give input like, comma separated string of different series then output should be like each series with hyphen and separated by comma only output should not be in table format.

Comment: If you want to replace every other comma in the string, then SQL is not the right tool.

Comment: This is something likely done far better by the user interface than SQL code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not Perfect Solution Still I'm Trying Please help out me.

```
alter procedure dbo.SequenceNumbersReplaceByHyphen
(@strInputList varchar(max), -- InputString
@Flag Bit) -- Bit Values 1,0
as

begin

    If @Flag = 1
        Begin

            create table dbo.#TempNumaric(Id Int Identity,Value Varchar(10))
            insert into #TempNumaric
            select substring(Value,1,len(Value)) as Value from dbo.Split2(@strInputList) where Value not like '%[^0-9]%'

            select stuff(convert(varchar(max), ( select ',' + case when min(Value) = max(Value) then convert(varchar(10), min(Value))
                                                                   else convert(varchar(10), min(Value)) + '-' + convert(varchar(10), max(Value)) end
            from #TempNumaric
            group by Value - Id
            for xml path(''))), 1, 1, '') as Result

        end

            create table dbo.#TempChar(Id Int Identity,Value Varchar(10))
            insert into #TempChar
            select substring(Value,1,len(Value)) as Value from dbo.Split2(@strInputList) where Value like '%[^0-9]%'

    If @Flag = 0
        Begin
        declare @I Int = (select min(Id) from #TempChar)
        declare @N Int = @@Rowcount
        while @I < = @N
            Begin
                select Id,Left(Value,1) as Char,Right(Value,len(Value)-1) as Value from #TempChar
                set @I= @I+1
            End

        end
        Drop Table #TempNumaric
        Drop Table #TempChar
End


--exec dbo.NumbersReplaceByHyphen '1,2,3,11,12,13,15,16,20,21,22,c1,c2,T1,T9,T11', 1 This is Working.

--exec dbo.NumbersReplaceByHyphen '1,2,3,11,12,13,15,16,20,21,22,c1,c2,T1,T9,T11', 0 This is I need to do.
```

Actually we need like this  1-3,11-13,15,16,20-22,C1-C2,T1,T9,T11

Wherever Sequence we need to replace Hyphen (-) and Comma Separated For example I/p:T1,T2,T3,T6,M1,M2,M7,M8,M9
                                                                                             o/p: T1-T3,T6,M1-M2,M7-M9

```
ALTER function [dbo].[Split2](@input AS Varchar(max) )
Returns  @Result Table(Value VARCHAR(MAX))
As
Begin
      Declare @str Varchar(20)
      Declare @ind Int
      If(@input is not null)
      Begin
            Set @ind = CharIndex(',',@input)
            While @ind > 0
            Begin
                  Set @str = SUBSTRING(@input,1,@ind-1)
                  Set @input = SUBSTRING(@input,@ind+1,LEN(@input)-@ind)
                  Insert Into @Result values (@str)
                  Set @ind = CharIndex(',',@input)
            End
            Set @str = @input
            Insert Into @Result values (@str)
      End
      Return
End                 


--select * from dbo.[Split2]('1,2,5,7,C1,C2,V1,V3,V4')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--exec SequenceSeriesReplaceByHyphen '1,2,3,11,12,13,15,16,20,21,22,C 1,C 2,C 3,C 5,C 6,C 9,72,73,T 1,T 2,T 5,T 99,55,56,57,60,61,V6,V7,V9,99,100,101' 


alter procedure dbo.SequenceSeriesReplaceByHyphen
@strInputList varchar(max)-- InputString
As

Begin

    create table dbo.#TempChar(Value Varchar(10))
    insert into #TempChar
    select Value from dbo.Split2(@strInputList) --where Value like '%[^0-9]%';

    ;With CteSplit(letter, number) 
     As(
     Select Ltrim(Rtrim(LEFT(Value, Patindex('%[0-9]%', Value) -1))),
               Cast(Right(Value, Len(Value) - Patindex('%[0-9]%', Value) + 1) AS Int)
     From #TempChar
       )
           ,Cte As (
                    Select *,RN = Number - Row_Number() Over(Partition By Letter Order BY Number)
                    From CteSplit
                    )
            ,CteFinal As(
                         Select Letter,
                                StartNumber = Min(number),
                                EndNumber = Max(number)
                         From   Cte
                         Group By letter, RN)
     Select Stuff((Select ',' + letter + '' + Cast(startNumber As varchar(Max)) +
                                              Case
                                              When startNumber = endNumber Then ''
                                              Else '-' + letter + '' + Cast(endNumber As varchar(Max))
                                              End
     From CteFinal
     Order By letter, startNumber, endNumber
     For xml Path('')),1, 1, '') as Result

End
```

---

```
ALTER function [dbo].[Split2](@input AS Varchar(max) )
Returns  @Result Table(Value VARCHAR(MAX))
As
Begin
      Declare @str Varchar(20)
      Declare @ind Int
      If(@input is not null)
      Begin
            Set @ind = CharIndex(',',@input)
            While @ind > 0
            Begin
                  Set @str = SUBSTRING(@input,1,@ind-1)
                  Set @input = SUBSTRING(@input,@ind+1,LEN(@input)-@ind)
                  Insert Into @Result values (@str)
                  Set @ind = CharIndex(',',@input)
            End
            Set @str = @input
            Insert Into @Result values (@str)
      End
      Return
End
```